# Loading Keycloak config from URL

Tags: javascript, keycloak, jboss-tools

The [Keycloak 3.2 Javascript Adapter documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html) says you can instantiate the keycloak object with :

```js
var keycloak = Keycloak('http://localhost:8080/myapp/keycloak.json'));
```

But when I try to do so, it looks like my keycloak.config file is not propertly set as I end up with :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
  at getRealmUrl (keycloak.js:482)
  at Keycloak.kc.createLoginUrl (keycloak.js:233)
  at Object.login (keycloak.js:897)
  at Keycloak.kc.login (keycloak.js:205)
  at doLogin (keycloak.js:121)
  at onLoad (keycloak.js:144)
  at Object.processInit [as successCallback] (keycloak.js:187)
  at Object.setSuccess (keycloak.js:771)
  at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (keycloak.js:598)
  at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (zone.js:1056)
```

Yet, when I access `http://localhost:8080/myapp/keycloak.json` with my browser I get :

```json
{
  url: 'http://keycloak-server/auth',
  realm: 'myrealm',
  clientId: 'myapp'
}
```

and if I instantiate the keycloak object with

```js
var keycloak = Keycloak({
   url: 'http://keycloak-server/auth',
   realm: 'myrealm',
   clientId: 'myapp'
});
```

everything works fine.

Is this a Keycloak bug, or is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keycloak uses a different format whether you load the config from its URL or straight into the constructor...

If you load it via its URL, the format has to be :

```json
{
  auth-server-url: 'http://keycloak-server/auth',
  realm: 'myrealm',
  resource: 'myapp'
}
```

and not

```json
{
  url: 'http://keycloak-server/auth',
  realm: 'myrealm',
  clientId: 'myapp'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my whole day

Comment: Sorry to add to this old question. It seems that currently keycloak, if you don't add any parameter to `Keycloak()`, tries to find `base_url/keycloak.json'. But I'm not serving my json file, is there a way to read it locally and load it into the constructor without using an http request?

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?